# Django Makemessages CommandError ASCII Encoding

Tags: python, django, translation, gettext

the locale/django.po file has 7868 lines. Sometimes the makemessages command works and sometimes it throws this error: Its strange because in the error is always a different line of django.pot mentioned.
And don't forget that it sometimes works with the same code, so the code should be fine

```
manage.py makemessages -l de
CommandError: errors happened while running msguniq
/app/xxx/locale/django.pot:1871: /app/xxx/locale/django.pot: input is not valid in "ASCII" encoding
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: no, unfortunately not. It's still so annoying

Comment: I have discovered that in my case the problem was in that there was no files with file extension like jinja.

Comment: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29452 this bug was fixed 5 days after your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andrey Shipilov mentioned in the comment, this seems to be fixed in Django 2.1 as of http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29452